# Google Login not working on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, login, google

I'm trying to ask a question on Stack Overflow, but when I try to log in I get to the following screen:

[image: Login Page]

I'm then redirected back to the main screen but I'm still not logged in.

[image: Main Screen]

Anyone else having this issue or have any idea of how to resolve it? Whatever I try, I just get into this cycle.

Comment: Did you try clearing your cache?

Comment: Are you using any FF extensions (I am thinking about HTTPS everwhere in particular)?

Comment: You should try clearing cache, and also 'Active Logins' and cookies.

Comment: That did the trick. I would have preferred a less nuclear option but works now. Thanks! @Cerbrus, if you make it an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: I wasn't using any extensions that I know of, not sure what was causing the issue.

Comment: @tjordan: Answered!

Comment: "ooh this screenshot looks nice" "oh, it's just because it's OS X"

Comment: I ran into this just the other day.  See the MSE question [Can't log in using Firefox in Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165468/225437).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor that is the same problem. I did a check for duplicates but thought the problem was with the Google login rather than Firefox so didn't catch it.

Comment: @bjb568 Not because OS X, but because Firefox <3

Comment: Eh, Safari looks good too. *pls don't kill me*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may need to clear your cache.

Sometimes, memory like that can have its state... "stuck", resulting in unexpected behavior. Starting over with a clean slate for a buggy website often helps.

Comment: For the future visitors, who may not know what cache is, or how to clear it,  a link on how to clear cache in various browsers is located [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic)

Comment: @PeterMortensen, while your edit is appreciated, your edit reason... Try to be less of a snob about it, will you?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, ignore them... your edit reason was a simple statement in fact.  There was no snobbery to be found.

Comment: @Cerbrus, sometimes, stackoverflow reminds me a lot of reddit.